# Excel file causes Excel to crash when saving file

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel (2007) file that I successfully save at work and email. The emailed version I can open with no problems. But when I try to save it in Excel 2010, it immediately hangs and goes to recover my files. Which it has no file since I have not had it open that long or saved a copy. I have tried it on another computer at home and the same thing happens. How do I find out what is causing this to happen?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest saving the file to your computer and then opening it up in 2010. At this point I wouldn't choose the save option, instead I would choose the "Save As" option and try different formats, the first I would try is xlsx. It's likely got some formatting issues and can't be saved in the format it currently exists.